# How to use variable values outside of the function in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html

This is part of the code. I did not get the value of Framesize after button click.

```
$("#Fs").keyup(function(e){
    Framesize=this.value;
    alert(Framesize);
});
$("input:button").click(function(e) {
    alert(Framesize);
});
```

Comment: just initialize the variable `var Framesize=null;`at the top

Comment: what you are doing should work, are you trying to click the button before typing any key?

Answer (score 0):

```
var Framesize = null;       // Put your variable in the global scope

$("#Fs").keyup(function(e){
    Framesize=this.value;
    alert(Framesize);
});
$("input:button").click(function(e) {
    alert(Framesize);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have declared (even though you didn't use a word **var**) a variable in one scope of anonymous function and have tried to use it in another scope of anonymous function. Basically the simplest solution to your problem (but maybe not the best for the long term) is to declare the variable **Framesize** in the global scope of your Javascript code:

```
var Framesize = null;
```

Now you can use it safely in every scope in your code and then access it again anywhere, because it's a global variable.